# Cannot find table from a SQLite database within R Shiny

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny, shiny-server, rsqlite

I have an sqlite database that contains a table "sae", and want to access this table from a Shiny interface. I tried the following code within RStudio command line:

```
library(RSQLite)
f.sae <- "link/to/my/data.db"
m <- dbDriver("SQLite")
con.sae <- dbConnect(m,dbname=f.sae)
```

That works fine both on command line and Shiny, but if I look at the content I get:

```
print(dbListTables(con.sae))
```

In command line:

```
[1] "sae"
```

In Shiny using runApp()

```
character(0)
```

This issue has already been discussed (see below) and the way Shiny changes the current working directory seems to be the reason,

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/-8S9PKeXLNw
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/sDVMbBNPc-s

but I could not however find a way around, even by forcing setwd().

Comment: I would suggest setting up a Project within R Studio: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects It makes it a lot easier to find files. Make sure that `data.db` is in the same folder as your app.r file. I'd recommend putting these files in their own subdirectory within the project directory.

Comment: Relevant read: https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/

Comment: Thanks, so if the db is constrained to sit in a different location than the app.R, Shiny won't be able to feed on it? I want to keep scripts and data apart.